# How to reason that the following sum is zero?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume the following summation,

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{1000}\left(-1\right)^{i}{1000 \choose i}\left(100 - i\right)^{500}.
$$

I know that this summation is zero, $0$ ( I've checked it with Maple, though ). But I cannot find any proof for that!. Can you provide any help ?.

P.S. This is not a homework problem, just a question one of my friend asked me.

Comment: Split into summing even and odd series and reduce maybe?

Comment: @Chinny84 I've done this, even I've expanded it using binomial theorem which gives me two nested sums. None of them helped me (I am not so good in counting and combinatorics)

Answer (score 1):

If $(Δ p)(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ denotes the step-one difference operator, your expression is equal to
$$0=(Δ^{1000} p)(x)\quad\text{where}\quad p(x)=(100-x)^{500}$$

Since each application of $Δ$ lowers the degree of the polynomial by one, already $(Δ^{501} p)(x)=0$, and moreso the higher order differences.

---

If $p(x)=x^k$, then 
$$
(Δ p)(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)=(x+1)^k-x^k=(x+1)^{k-1}+(x+1)^{k-2}x+...+(x+1)x^{k-2}+x^{k-1}
$$
is a polynomial of one degree less, this extends linearly to all polynomials. Thus $\deg(Δ^m p)=\deg p-m$ as long as $m\le\deg p$, and $Δ^{1+\deg p} p=0$.

For the higher order differences on gets the formula
$$
(Δ^m p)(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i} p(x+i)
$$
This is obviously true for $m=0$, and easy to check for $m=1$, let's do the induction step
\begin{align}
(Δ^{m+1} p)(x)&=(Δ^m p)(x+1)-(Δ^m p)(x)
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i} p(x+i+1)-\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i} p(x+i)
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(-1)^{m-i+1}\binom{m}{i-1} p(x+i)+\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{m-i+1}\binom{m}{i} p(x+i)
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m+1}(-1)^{m+1-i}\binom{m+1}{i} p(x+i)
\end{align}

---

Even easier is the derivation using the translation operator $(Tp)(x)=p(x+1)$. Then $Δ=(T-I)$ and 
$$
Δ^m=(T-I)^m=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}(-1)^{m-i}T^{i}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get the intuition of your argument. Would you mind explaining this further?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{i=0}^{1000}\pars{-1}^{i}{1000 \choose i}\pars{100 - i}^{500} = 0:\
     {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{i=0}^{1000}\pars{-1}^{i}{1000 \choose i}\pars{100 - i}^{500}
> =\sum_{i=0}^{1000}\pars{-1}^{i}{1000 \choose i}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{500}
> {500 \choose \ell}100^{500 - \ell}\pars{-i}^{\ell}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{500}{500 \choose \ell}\pars{-1}^{\ell}100^{500 - \ell}
> \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{1000}{1000 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}i^{\ell}}
> _{\ds{=\ 0;\quad\mbox{See bellow}}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\pars{1 - z}^{1000}&=\sum_{i = 0}^{1000}{1000 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}z^{i}
\\
-1000z\pars{1 - z}^{999}&=\sum_{i = 0}^{1000}{1000 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}iz^{i}
\\
-1000z\pars{1 - z}^{999} + 1000\times999 z^{2}\pars{1 - z}^{998}&
=\sum_{i = 0}^{1000}{1000 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}i^{2}z^{i}\,,
\end{align}
If we continue this procedure we get increasing powers of $i$ ( up to $i^{\ell}$ with $\ell \leq 500$ ) in the right member.
Then, set $z = 1$ in both members and we'see that all the sums vanish out.